# Postgresql replication: using 2 BDR with/and 2*n UDR or pglogical (some kind of DataCenter setup)

Tags: postgresql, replication, postgresql-bdr

I plan to run a replicated `Postgresql` over multiple sites. There should be two servers on every site. At the main site they should run in `BDR` mode. And between the sites (to the other servers) I need something like `UDR`.
I could use `BDR` if it would not require full-mesh connections and would cascade the changes.

I was reading that `BDR` and `UDR` are not working well together.
[link](http://postgresql.nabble.com/BDR-setup-bdr-node-join-wait-for-ready-td5863606.html)
Then I have seen `pglogical` which looks like a `UDR` replacement. [pglogical docs](http://2ndquadrant.com/en/resources/pglogical/pglogical-docs/)
I am using BDR Version 0.9.3 (postgresql 9.4).

Can I mix `BDR` with `UDR` the way I want?
Can I mix `BDR` and `pglogical` to achieve what I want?
What might be critical or a pitfall?
Is there any way to do this with the currently available versions? What will be the needed version and the procedure to get this working?

Edit: 
I was thinking about a `UDR` direction from the `BDR` servers to the other servers. But I could also imagine other peaople need it the other way around. Or some tables sync up only while others sync down only.

Edit2:

I tried to use `BDR` with `pglogical`.

1. First I did the 2 node `BDR` setup.
2. Verified it is working.
3. Then I did the `pglogical` setup just on one `BDR` node.
4. From this point on it stopped working (`BDR` & `pglogical`).

Seams like `pglogical` locks `DDL` (or maybe everything).
I could not join a subscriber and I was not able to insert data on the other `BDR` node (`DDL` locked).

So at the moment it seams to be **NOT** possible to run `BDR` and `pglogical` on the same tables.
But there might be a workaround - or I may have done something wrong.